# Can I get the real type through pointer using decltype() or something else?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
class Foo {

};

class Bar : public Foo {

};

int main() {
  Foo* foo = new Bar;

  std::cout << typeid(decltype(*foo)).name() << std::endl;
}
```

I tried some syntax, with or without `decltype`, but the results are all about type `Foo`. Any way I can get type `Bar` through pointer of type `Foo`?

P.S. I only want get the type information at runtime, any hacks are welcome.

Edit: the if/else and `dynamic_cast` trick is not very acceptable if I got lots of types.

Comment: At compile time I don't think that's possible, however at runtime using `dynamic_cast` you can check the type.

Comment: @frogatto the problem is that there are a lot of types, I can't use if/else to check all of them.

Comment: `decltype` is determined at compile time, and trying to use something whose type you don't know is usually futile. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The dynamic type of a pointer is a runtime property you cannot extract at compile-time. There might be other ways to achieve your true goal though.

Comment: This is not a XY problem because I didn't get a problem, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the dynamic type of an object can only be obtained for polymorphic class types, meaning the base class must have at least one virtual function.

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
};

class Bar : public Foo {

};
```

Second, the dynamic type is obtained by applying `typeid` operator directly to the expression referencing the object:

```
int main() {
    Foo* foo = new Bar;

    std::cout << typeid(*foo).name() << std::endl;
}
```

`decltype` is a compile-time only operator.

Comment: So it seems that `typeid` is a run-time operator,  right?

Comment: It is. By definition, the dynamic type can not be known at compile time. Even if applied to a type or to a non-polymorphic expression (so that `typeid` returns the static type), its return type is a reference to `std::type_info`, which is a runtime object. Therefore, unlike `decltype`, `typeid` is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `dynamic_cast`.

From reference: dynamic_cast will be return `nullptr` if pointed object not object of that type

For example .

```
class Foo {
public:
  virtual ~Foo() = default; // To make foo polymorphic
};

class Bar : public Foo {};

//....
Foo *foo = new Bar;

if (dynamic_cast<Foo *>(foo) == nullptr) {
   std::cout << "Not a bar!" << std::endl;
} else {
   std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
}
//....
```

NOTE: this approach works only at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because Foo is not a **polymorphic** type.
This example works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Foo {
public:
    virtual void foo() {} // This makes Foo a polymorphic type
};

class Bar : public Foo {
};

int main() {
  Foo* foo = new Bar;
  std::cout << typeid(*foo).name() << std::endl;
}
```